# Reading all Access files in folder in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to import all of the data from multiple Access files (identical structure) in a SQL Server table using SSIS.

I created a foreach container, put a data task in it, and an oledb source and destination. I set up the foreach to loop thru all the files in the folder, and assigned a filename to a variable. After that I set up an expression for the oledb connection and thats where the problem starts.

Every time as soon as I add the expression (assigning the connection string or server name in expression) I get an error (DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER, 0x80004005) on the source and connection manager and can't do anything with it. I am selecting Microsoft.ACE12 Data provider and normally (outside of foreach and no expressions) it all works. But I need to loop thru all the files and every tutorial I found on the Internet lists these same steps, nothing else.

Thanx

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444098/how-to-import-multiple-access-databases-into-sql-server-using-ssis

Comment: I did again everything as written here, and the same thing happens :(